# In Activity.class want to get Spinner Item Text from Fragment.class

Tags: android, spinner

im still confused about to get spinner item text.

So, In **Activity.class** i want to **get Spinner Item Text from Fragment.class** but idk how to get Spinner Item Text from fragment,

anyone can help?

Fragment.class

```
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.choices);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                       int postion, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String SpinerValue3 = parent.getItemAtPosition(postion).toString();

                if (SpinerValue3.equals("Item 1")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                            "Try Choose : " + SpinerValue3,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();=
                } else if (SpinerValue3.equals("Item 2")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                            "Try Choose : " + SpinerValue3,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if (SpinerValue3.equals("Item 3")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                            "Try Choose : " + SpinerValue3,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if (SpinerValue3.equals("Item 4")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                            "Try Choose : " + SpinerValue3,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if (SpinerValue3.equals("Item 5")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                            "Try Choose : " + SpinerValue3,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if (SpinerValue3.equals("Item 6")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                            "Try Choose : " + SpinerValue3,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
            @Override
             public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

if above im explain for make a toast, but how to **get text spinner item on Activity.class**

Activity.class  Iwant to change **SPINNERITEM** (On code below) with g**et Spinner item text from Fragment**

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RekomendasiExercise extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = AbdominalFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String url = "http://........php";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Exercise> exerciseList = new ArrayList<Exercise>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    public RekomendasiExercise() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.choices);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, exerciseList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        if(exerciseList.isEmpty()) {
            // Creating volley request obj
            JsonArrayRequest exerciseReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                            hidePDialog();

                            exerciseList.clear();

                            // Parsing json
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                try {
                                    String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                                    int positionitem = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

                                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Exercise exercise = new Exercise();
                                    if (obj.getString("type").equals("SPINNERITEM")) {
                                        exercise.setNama(obj.getString("name"));

                                        exercise.setTipe(obj.getString("type"));
                                        exercise.setMainmuscle(obj.getString("mainmuscle"));


                                        exerciseList.add(exercise);
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }

                            // notifying list adapter about data changes
                            // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();

                }
            });

            // Adding request to request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(exerciseReq);
        }else{
            hidePDialog();
        }

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View convertView, int position, long id) {
        // Create custom dialog object
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

        // Include dialog.xml file
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog); // layout of your dialog

        // Set dialog title
        dialog.setTitle("Detail");

        // set values for custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView nama = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.nama);
        nama.setText("Nama = " + exerciseList.get(position).getNama());
        // similar add statements for other details

        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the code that you have so far (see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), this a) shows that you've not just fishing for someone to write code on your behalf and b) it would likely highlight more specifically about what is confusing and thus a more specific and helpful answer could be given.

Comment: Update my code for Fragment.class when im declare the spinner, but idk how to `get spinnet item text on` **Activity.class**

Comment: Tip on java terminology: You are editing java files that contain definitions of classes, not class files themselves

Comment: Instead of making a String, You can create a View which stores the selected view from the spinner and then use 'getText()' on that view

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to follow the standard communication model for `Activity` and `Fragment` where the `Activity` implements a callback interface defined in the Fragment.

Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) for details.

In your `onItemSelected` method of the spinner, you can call the callback method of the `Activity` with the selected spinner value.

Comment: im already follow from Android Developer, but can you explain it from my code ?

Comment: If you are already following the Android developer guide, then could you please post your code for the Activity where you have implemented the Fragment listener interface?

Comment: Update My code with Activity.class, in activity class you can see `SPINNERITEM` , and exactly this is place for me get spinnet item text from Fragment

Answer (score 0):

### **This is how you could do in OOPS ways**

Step 1) **Make a spinner Item Value variable in Activity Class**

```
    public class RekomendasiExercise extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
    
    private String currentSpinnerItem ;


    /*
     set current spinner item value
    */
    
    public void setCurrentSpinnerItem(String itemValue)
    {  
    this.currentSpinnerItem  = itemValue ;
    
    //Do stuffs in activity with new value 
    }
```

Step 2) **Now in your fragment class update currentItemSpinner value like this**

```
@Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                   int postion, long arg3) {
          
            String SpinerValue3 = parent.getItemAtPosition(postion).toString();

    //Update spinner selected item value in activity
((RekomendasiExercise) getActivity).setCurrentSpinnerItem(SpinerValue3);
  }
```